# Warning: UICollectionViewFlowLayout has cached frame mismatch for index path 'abc'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

This is the code causing the warning:

```
private override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let distance = CGRectGetMidX(attributes!.frame) - self.midX;
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -distance, 0, -self.width);
    attributes!.transform3D = CATransform3DIdentity;
    return attributes
}
```

The console also prints:

> This is likely occurring because the flow layout "xyz" is modifying attributes returned by UICollectionViewFlowLayout without copying them.

How do I fix this warning?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> This is likely occurring because the flow layout "xyz" is modifying attributes returned by UICollectionViewFlowLayout without copying them

And sure enough, that's just what you are doing:

```
private override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let distance = CGRectGetMidX(attributes!.frame) - self.midX;
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -distance, 0, -self.width);
    attributes!.transform3D = CATransform3DIdentity;
    return attributes
}
```

I expect that if you simply say:

```
let attributes = 
    super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath).copy() 
    as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
```

or similar, the problem will go away.

Comment: In Swift 2, you can't call copy() on super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath. However you can call it on the individual layout attributes, then put those into an array and return that instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31508225/1259702

Comment: @TrevorAlyn yes you can. Here is an example of me doing it. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/af4c7daca57b5a995d6c8b59b3362a45712cefdb/bk2ch08p466collectionViewFlowLayout2/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/MyFlowLayout.swift and the code I give in my answer is Swift 2 and works fine.

Comment: @matt: Oops -- I was trying to call copy() on layoutAttributesForElementsInRect, not layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath. But Xcode gives me a "has no member copy" error when I try to do this: 
        var attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect).copy()

Comment: @TrevorAlyn If you don't copy it, is it giving you the same error?

Comment: Nope. Fortunately I can copy the individual attributes, like so:

attributesCopy.append(attributes![0].copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)

Comment: @TrevorAlyn Right but if you're not having a problem I don't see why you need to make a copy.

Comment: @matt: I'm copying them so I can make adjustments to them.

Comment: **In Swift4.1** I used `override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var array: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
        for object in  super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)! {
            array.append(object.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)
        }`

Answer (score 43):

In addition to the great answer above.

I know the example code is written in swift, but I thought that it can be helpful to have the Objective-C version.

For Objective-C, this won't work, because the copy function does only a shallow copy. You will have to do this:

```
NSArray * original   = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
NSArray * attributes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:original copyItems:YES];
```

I have added a temp variable for readability.

Comment: In addition :

my answer is handy when You use an array of attributes, if You want to get only the attributes for a specific indexPath see the answer of Ayman Ibrahim

Answer (score 23):

I had this issue when overriding `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`.  Iterating through each element in the `super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)` array and calling copy wasn't working for me, so I ended up falling back on Foundation classes and using `NSArray`'s `copyItems`:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    // unwrap super's attributes
    guard let superArray = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) else { return nil }

    // copy items
    guard let attributes = NSArray(array: superArray, copyItems: true) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] else { return nil }

    // modify attributes

    return attributes
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this even though there was another answer. I was iterating through each element in an array and copying as well. Wasn't working for me either. So thanks for posting this solution.

Comment: @JAL, how to append attributes to it. because its a NSArray

Comment: @Ranjit cast the `NSArray` as a Swift Array like I do with the `attributes` variable

Comment: @JAL, I solved the copy issue, but I am facing one more issue, I have created a SO question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146913/uicollectionview-custom-flow-layout-crashes-on-scrolling

Answer (score 10):

It's not the answer to original question, but can help for layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) (Swift 3.0):

```
let safeAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
safeAttributes?.forEach { /* do something with attributes*/ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @Georgi answer

`<NSCopying>` must be conformed and add copy message call to `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] copy];
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated response for Swift 3!

for func layoutAttributesForElements

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let attributesToReturn =  attributes.map( { $0.copy() }) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] else {
        return nil
    }

    return attributesToReturn

}
```

for func layoutAttributesForItem

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

    guard let currentItemAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes else {
        return nil
    }

    return currentItemAttributes
}
```

If you override both function, you have to call copy on both function!

Good coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Inside `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect()` I did this change:

change from

```
guard let attributesForItem: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {
    return
}
```

change to

```
guard let attributesForItem = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes else {
    return
}
```