# when using subclassed collectionViewFlowLayout I'm getting weird error

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I made a subclass of `collectionViewFlowLayout`. After that, I implemented the following code:

```
override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attr = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)
        attr?.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8), CGFloat(M_PI))
        attr?.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.collectionView!.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.collectionView!.bounds))
        return attr
    }
```

When I delete items in collection view using `performBatchUpdates`: method the debugger throws this error message. The deletion actually succeeds and is fully working, but I am a little confused about this debugger output. Can someone please explain should I do to please debugger? I don't really understand what code and where should be added.

//ERROR MESSAGE

> 2015-08-02 12:39:42.208 nameOfMyProject[1888:51831] Logging only once
>   for UICollectionViewFlowLayout cache mismatched frame 2015-08-02
>   12:39:42.209 nameOfMyProject[1888:51831] UICollectionViewFlowLayout
>   has cached frame mismatch for index path  {length = 2, path = 0 - 11} - cached value:
>   {{106.13333333333333, 131.13333333333333}, {75.733333333333348,
>   75.733333333333348}}; expected value: {{192.5, 288}, {94.666666666666671, 94.666666666666671}}
>
> 2015-08-02 12:39:42.209 nameOfMyProject[1888:51831] This is likely
>   occurring because the flow layout subclass nameOfMyProject.ShopLayout
>   is modifying attributes returned by UICollectionViewFlowLayout without
>   copying them
>
> 2015-08-02 12:39:42.209 nameOfMyProject[1888:51831] Snapshotting a
>   view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure
>   your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or
>   snapshot after screen updates.

Comment: Did this only start happening with Xcode 7? Something very similar has been happening to me as well since updating to Xcode 7 (and installing iOS9). I'm Obj-C, not swift, but the error is telling you you're not copying the attributes before changing them. I tried doing something like `NSArray *allAttributesInArray = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] copy];` before manipulating them, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: i never used collection view before xcode 7. I ended up using a plain old flowLayout without subclassing so I cant really provide an answer

Comment: @wanderingme have you found out how to solve this? I have got the same one and nothing has helped to solve it yet.

Comment: I did, but for Obj-C and using a custom subclass called TLLayoutTransitioning. I mentioned my workaround here: https://github.com/wtmoose/TLLayoutTransitioning/issues/26

Comment: TL;DR version: I reloaded the UICollectionView data before transitioning between my two UICollectionViewFlowLayouts.

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31508153/1470581

Answer (score 11):

The error occurs because you are manipulating the attribute without copying it first. So this should fix the error:

```
override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attr = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)?.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    // manipulate the attr
    return attr
}
```

When you come across the same error in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect)` you have to copy each of the items in the array instead of just copying the array:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
        var attributesCopy = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for itemAttributes in attributes! {
            let itemAttributesCopy = itemAttributes.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
            // manipulate itemAttributesCopy
            attributesCopy.append(itemAttributesCopy)
        }
        return attributesCopy
    }
```

Comment: Copying all the attributes in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect solved the warnings.

Comment: @Ranjit Have you had a look at the github issue mentioned in the comments above? (https://github.com/wtmoose/TLLayoutTransitioning/issues/26)

Comment: @joern, looking at it.