# Logging only once for UICollectionViewFlowLayout cache mismatched frame

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have created an app which I used the `JSQMessageViewController` and it works fine in iOS 8. I used Swift in this project and I do bridging since the library is written in Objective-C. But after the released of iOS 9, Xcode 7, and Swift 2, I converted my code syntax to Swift 2 and the problems comes.. The app was not crashed but there is a log error… See below.

```
2015-09-23 14:45:08.867 COC REAL WAR[1201:546997] Logging only once for UICollectionViewFlowLayout cache mismatched frame  
2015-09-23 14:45:08.868 COC REAL WAR[1201:546997] UICollectionViewFlowLayout has cached frame mismatch for index path <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5} - cached value: {{4, 693.221}, {312, 97}}; expected value: {{4, 596}, {312, 97}}  
2015-09-23 14:45:08.868 COC REAL WAR[1201:546997] This is likely occurring because the flow layout subclass JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout is modifying attributes returned by UICollectionViewFlowLayout without copying them
```

Answers are much appreciated.

Comment: While the current answer may solve your problem,it is not what needs to be done, xcode is telling you that you are returning new attributes while you should return the attributes from the superclass, changing some of them if needed. Could you post your `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`? I can point you to your mistake.

Comment: This was answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106089/12039062). This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this was the right answer but just found an answer from [link](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout/issues/4). I'm just changing the springinessEnabled to false..

*collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false*

Comment: This worked for me!! I was getting a full on crash too. Plus it runs much better without the springyness.

Comment: It's your question, so you have to vote it as the answer. I've already up voted it.