# Strange disappearing items when scrolls

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegate

Presets,

i have collectionViewFlowLayout subclass with

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
   }

- (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *arr = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    BBLog(@"ARRA:%@", arr);
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr in arr) {
        if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(attr.transform)) {
            attr.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

CollectionView rotate to upside down scroll with

```
 self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI);
```

But even if jus use native collectionViewFlowLayout without subclassing, a git this error

Problem

I have two messages and more in chat, but when scroll at bottom (top normally) disappear second item.

layoutAttributesForElementsInRect for given rect return two attributes for two indexPaths 0-0 and 0-1, but delegate method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

called only for indexPath 0-0

Here images

[image: TopScroll]
[image]

**UPDATE**
So i found WHY it's happen - this line code

```
attr.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI);
```

Look if remove transform

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, all, but i found reason and work around.

This happen only on device not on simulator

Look at three CGRects

**iPhone 5S**

```
(CGRect) oldFrame = (origin = (x = -0.000000000000056843418860808015, y = 0), size = (width = 320.00000000000006, height = 314.00000000000006))
```

**iPhone 5C**

(CGRect) oldFrame = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 314))

**Simulator Intel Core**

```
(CGRect) oldFrame = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 314))
```

To all of them i apply rotation transform via

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI)
```

First it's on iPhone 5S **ARM Apple A7** CPU

Second it's on iPhone 5C **ARM Apple A6** CPU

Third it's on Simulator at Intel Core iX processor.

So, my work around is:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *retAttr = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(retAttr.transform)) {
        retAttr.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI);
    }

    CGRect oldFrame = retAttr.frame;

    oldFrame.origin.x = retAttr.frame.origin.x > 0 ?: 0;

    retAttr.frame = oldFrame;

    return retAttr;
}
```

Comment: any solution for swift ?

Comment: In swift did not test, now coding only in objc. But i think same problem will be.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but I think that, when You are subclassing the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, You are not supposed to modify the attributes directly, but to make a copy of the attributes, modify it instead and return it.

Short explanation of the top statement :
You will have to subclass the UICollectionViewFlowDelegate ( the parent of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ) and than make your own attributes and modify them as You wish, but this will require of to implement a lot more custom logic.

Also look if You are getting any errors or warnings in the console.

Check out this question : [Warning: UICollectionViewFlowLayout has cached frame mismatch for index path 'abc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508153/im-getting-a-warning-in-xcode-uicollectionviewflowlayout-has-cached-frame-mis/33172179#33172179)

Hope that I was at least a little helpful.