# UICollectionView AutoLayout max width?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm having a  dilemma maybe someone can  help. I followed this tutorial that showed me how to dynamically adjust the height of a `collectionview` to match the height of the text. 
https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel/

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout { flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1) }

cell.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 50
```

But the issue I'm having is now the collection view wraps around the text instead of conforming to `collectionView.bounds.width`. So when i have text that is smaller than the `collectionview` width, the cell wraps around the text. I want the cell to match the height of the text but have a set width set to collectionview bounds. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You have a great answer to your problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143591/specifying-one-dimension-of-cells-in-uicollectionview-using-auto-layout) written by algal

Comment: Try flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.width, 1) but make sure your collection view already has it's proper width at this time.